# FET array - logical switch

Tags: mosfet, switches, logic-gates, fet

This is the circuit I plan to implement to control a LED by a logic bit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNQFLf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The datasheet of the transistor can be found [here](http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/SSM6N35FE,LM/SSM6N35FELMTR-ND/2257778)

I used FET transistor as amplifier, so I know about the saturation zone that let you get a voltage gain. However, I never used fet as switch, therefore correct if I am wrong.

In that zone, the MOSFET behave as a variable resistance. So if I work in 3.3 logic, when I put 1 into the gate, The mosfet will behave as a 2-4 ohms resistance (from the datasheet), where the channel will let pass current up to 50 mA? When I put a 0 into the gate ( Vgs < Vth) , the mosfet will not conduct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks good.

A few things to consider.

This FET looks good but when using other types be careful about the extremes of gate threshold voltage, many common types such as 2N7000 have a worst case threshold of >3V and so are not suitable for use with 3.3V logic.

The voltage required for the LED varies with the color - red is lowest at ~1.7V green is next at ~2.1 but blue and white may need more than 3V and so can't be driven from a 3.3V power rail without some more complexity (a charge pump for instance).

These days you can get enough light out of an LED for most uses with only 1-2mA.

Since the current requirement is so low you can drive the LED straight from a logic signal  (with a resistor) and you don't really need a discrete driver.

Comment: I will only use red & green LED, the world purpose is to show a "is charging" and "is complete" signal.